# How to continue loading after window.stop()? in chrome extension contentscript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection, instrumentation

I'm trying to modify a content of a webpage, specifically I want to replace the links to the scripts on the page to something else. The way I do it is putting the following code on top of my contentscript.js of the extension:

```
window.stop();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', location.href);
request.onload = function(event) {
  var html = request.responseText
    .replace('old link' 'new link');
    
  console.log(html);

  document.open();
  document.write(html);
  document.close();
};

request.send(null);
```

Even though I write the html into the document the execution just stops and the website doesn't finish loading. So what am I missing? What do I need to call to continue the execution?

Comment: There's a simpler method: use [declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) to add a redirect rule for the script url. You can also limit the rule to this site in its initiatorDomains. This API is available in MV2 and MV3.

Comment: @wOxxOm So if you got you right, at the bottom of the webpage there's a script

```
<script async defer src="https://heroesru-a.akamaihd.net/ok/v0943/assets/heroes.js" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
I added the following rule

[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action": { "type": "redirect", "redirect": { "url": "https://www.hw-assist.org/dummy_script.js" } },
  "condition": { "urlFilter": "https://heroesru-a.akamaihd.net/ok/v0943/assets/heroes.js", "resourceTypes": ["script"] }
 }
]
```
And added it to manifest. Still nothing...

Comment: @wOxxOm Also added "declarativeNetRequest" to permissions section of manifest.

Comment: Add `"host_permissions": ["https://heroesru-a.akamaihd.net/", "https://www.hw-assist.org/"]` to manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm It does work when I just create a dummy page and load that script there, but since the script has crossorigin="anonymous" on the dummy page it won't load, so I removed it. On an original website it doesn't replace the script and I suspect the crossorigin property is a problem. So it seems like I do need to modify the html in any case to at least to remove the crossorigin property?

Comment: I guess you should also add the URL of the site to host_permissions.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, now I'm getting somewhere, now I get this error, guess it has to do with cross orogin restrictions, is there a way around it? Access to script at 'https://www.hw-assist.org/dummy_script.js' (redirected from 'https://heroesru-a.akamaihd.net/ok/v0943/assets/heroes.js') from origin 'https://www.hero-wars.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Try setting this header to `*` or to the site's domain in another rule with urlFilter for your new script url.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not sure I understand, which header and what should I write in a second rule? Starting to look it'll be easier to just write my own CEF aplication than solve this :)

Comment: The header in the error e.g. "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*"

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, now it works now!!! So I just need to beatufy 8M of minified JS to be able to debug it properly :) Do you want to write a full answer so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: It'd be more useful for posterity if you make an answer with your actual code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, will do. BTW, if I redirect a script request, do I have to redirect it to a js file, or can it be any service returning a script? So if I want to add instrumentation to the script and inject my code, can I write, let's say, a php code that will send a request for initial script, inject a code in there and then return it back as part of a rule?

Comment: The `js` file extension is just a convenience, the browser doesn't care how the server processes it and the browser can't know or care whether it's a remote file or if it was a generated response. Your php server can do anything you want as long as it sends the response.